# How to submit value to database with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

so basically i want to make a webpage to detect how many times user clicked on it and send that value to database. I know i should use ajax but just can't figure out how to use it.

```
var count = 0;

$("body").click(function() {

$("#track").text("you clicked " + count + " times");

count++;

});

$.ajax({
url: "index.html",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#results").append(count);
}
});
```

Comment: To insert data to database you will need a database

Comment: @IsraGab The question clearly is tagged with PHP & DataBase... `:)`

Comment: I have a database that's not a problem..or i have to ocnnect with it with jquery? @IsraGab

Comment: jQuery will post the data to a PHP script, which will handle inserting that data into a DB.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question following the code you have posted. You may have to send your data using ajax. But to which URL? to wich format? that depends on server. Because Server need to intercept that data in order to store it in db

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, I didn't notice because there is no backend code

Comment: @nitring Did ya check my answer for a head start? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following things. You:

- have AMP Stack installed with PHP & MySQL.
- have a working DataBase in MySQL (most commonly used with PHP).
- are running the web server and looking at HTTP version and not file version in Chrome.

I would go by this method:

1. On load, I'll get the current count from DataBase using a PHP backend.

   1. In the PHP backend, I'll write a code to query MySQL and get the current value.
   2. Use a single file, say `count.php` as a file to get and set the counts.
   3. Using `GET` method, the file responds with the count.
   4. Use an AJAX code and get the count data.
   5. Using jQuery with the AJAX's response, update the DOM with the current count.
2. Once you load the page and update the value, set the event listener on click.

   1. Update the current count in the UI by adding one more.
   2. Use the same code as you have to update the UI to increment the count.
   3. Fire a `POST` request using AJAX to the `count.php` and send the new value.
   4. In the `count.php`, write an `UPDATE` query to update the count.
   5. Send a success message.
3. When you reload the page or look at the database, the count will be preserved.